# Accessing nested objects with reactive table in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I'm trying to display contacts in a table where it's possible to enter multiple contacts for the same address. I defined the settings for reactive table like this :

```
Template.masterlist.helpers({
  settings: function() {
    return {
      collection: Prospects,
      rowsPerPage: 10,
      showFilter: true,
      showColumnToggles: true,
      fields: [
        {
          'key': 'address.streetNumber',
          label: 'Street Number'
        }, {
          'key': 'address.streetName',
          label: 'Street Name'
        }, {
          'key': 'address.streetApp',
          label: 'App.'
        }, {
          'key': 'address.city',
          label: 'City'

            }, {
              'key': 'address.province',
              label: 'Province'
            }, {
              'key': 'address.postalCode',
              label: 'Postal Code'
            }, {
              'key': 'contacts.0.name',
              label: 'Name'
            }, {
              'key': 'contacts.0.phone',
              label: 'Phone'
            }, {
              'key': 'contacts.0.email',
              label: 'Email'
            }, {
              'key': 'contacts.0.notes',
              label: 'Notes'
            }
          ]
        };
      }
```

The problem is that it displays only the contact info for the first contact at this address I tried using [0] instead of just '0' but it didn't change anything.

Any idea?

Comment: This might help you a little: contacts.0.name is the name of the 1st contact. contacts.1.name is the name of the second contact and so on

Comment: Thank you for replying, I know this but what I want to know is if there is a kind of wildcard that would show the contacts info of all my contact

Comment: I'm guessing you have to use a custom cell to show multiple pieces of information